# File transfer speed : SCP vs Copy-Paste over SSH

Tags: file-transfer, scp, nano

Recently, I've been transferring some files between a device on my local network and my computer, and I've noticed something.

For a text file of approximately 2.5Mb

- Transfer using `scp file.txt user@hostip:/tmp/file.txt` -> Done almost instantly
- Transfer by using copy and paste in nano over ssh -> Take almost 15 minutes

So I was wondering why is there such a difference between the two methods ? Is there a way to make it work faster with the copy/paste method ?

(I know that in practice using the scp command is the right thing to do, but I'm just asking out of curiosity)

Comment: Nano probably does a lot of processing per character. How fast is `cat > file.txt`? (Use ctrl-d to finish writing; you may just have to press enter first though, since it has to be at the start of a line.)